# Make a "for i in $(...) in bash" command on linux

Tags: bash

I'm trying to execute a command line on each .jpg file in folder:

```
for i in ls *.jpg; do convert $i -resize 400x511 -gravity center -background white -extent 400x511 $i; done
```

But only the first .jpg is "done", what is wrong ?

Comment: you do not need the `ls`: `for i in *.jpg; do...; done`

Comment: @NilsWerner: You're right, i edit : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need `ls` here and 2nd you need to quote it.

```
for i in *.jpg; do
    convert "$i" -resize 400x511 -gravity center -background white -extent 400x511 "$i"
done
```

Comment: Insert `echo "$i"` before `convert` line and see how many times does it get echoed.

Comment: All files are printeds bu just one is modified by covert.

Comment: Oh great to know it is working. File names can have spaces also thats why it is important to quote the shell variables.